# gdb ptype print integer suffix to indicate it is signed, unsigned, unsigned long etc

Tags: c++, debugging, integer, gdb, suffix

how to set gdb setting to print integer suffix in ptype command

older gdb versions print integer suffix but with update the gdb(i think) the suffix is removed

actual :-

```
(gdb) ptype /m TestDataTemplate 
type = struct TestDataTemplate {
TestDataTemplateObj3<int, 2> m_obj3Int2;
}

---------

(gdb) ptype /m TestDataTemplate 
type = struct TestDataTemplate {
TestDataTemplateObj3<int, 2ul> m_obj3Int2;
}
```

expected it to print suffix for integers 
example : 45ul - unsigned long
          5ll  - signed long long

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a GDB issue, rather a GCC issue.  The type name you're seeing is encoded into the debug information.

I started with this test program:

```
template <typename T, unsigned long I>
class MyTemplateClass
{
  T array[I];
};

struct MyStructType
{
  MyTemplateClass<int, 2ul> ArrayOf2Int;
};

MyStructType obj;

int
main ()
{
  return 0;
}
```

which I compiled with GCC ( version 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6) ), and here's my debug session with GDB ( version Fedora 8.0.1-36.fc27 ):

```
(gdb) start
# .... snip ....
(gdb) ptype obj
type = struct MyStructType {
    MyTemplateClass<int, 2> ArrayOf2Int;
}
(gdb)
```

Notice that despite the template parameter being `unsigned long`, and being specialised with `2ul`, GDB still reports the type as `MyTemplateClass<int, 2>`.

Now if we look in the DWARF using `objdump -W ...` then here's what we see:

```
 ... snip ...

 <1><31>: Abbrev Number: 2 (DW_TAG_class_type)
    <32>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0xf6e): MyTemplateClass<int, 2>
    <36>   DW_AT_byte_size   : 8
    <37>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <38>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 2
    <39>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0x61>
 <2><3d>: Abbrev Number: 3 (DW_TAG_member)
    <3e>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x1b9f): array
    <42>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <43>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 4
    <44>   DW_AT_type        : <0x61>
    <48>   DW_AT_data_member_location: 0
 <2><49>: Abbrev Number: 4 (DW_TAG_template_type_param)
    <4a>   DW_AT_name        : T
    <4c>   DW_AT_type        : <0x78>
 <2><50>: Abbrev Number: 5 (DW_TAG_template_value_param)
    <51>   DW_AT_name        : I
    <53>   DW_AT_type        : <0x71>
    <57>   DW_AT_const_value : 8 byte block: 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 <2><60>: Abbrev Number: 0

 ... snip ...

 <1><7f>: Abbrev Number: 10 (DW_TAG_structure_type)
    <80>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0xa5f): MyStructType
    <84>   DW_AT_byte_size   : 8
    <85>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <86>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 7
    <87>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0x98>
 <2><8b>: Abbrev Number: 3 (DW_TAG_member)
    <8c>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x155a): ArrayOf2Int
    <90>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <91>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 9
    <92>   DW_AT_type        : <0x31>
    <96>   DW_AT_data_member_location: 0
 <2><97>: Abbrev Number: 0

 ... snip ...
```

If you're not familiar reading DWARF, then the main take away is that the type name of the `ArrayOf2Int` member is `MyTemplateClass<int, 2>`, and this is provided by GCC.

Why or when GCC changed, I can't tell you.

Comment: i was able to find the problem was with gcc.

Is it possible to get the same output as in gcc 5.4.0 which is able to print the integer suffix.

i tried various gcc debugging options ex: -g-version, -gdwarf-version

Do you know of any?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the gcc version
GCC version 5.4.0 is able to provide the suffix unlike 7.3

Maybe it is still possible by passing gcc arguments (still in search)
tried -gdwarf-version

Helpful if someone could provides input on arguments to be passed to gcc to get the same debugging information.